# Как можно определить положение элемента по оси "Z"?

Tags: javascript

Коллеги, есть такой пример:

```js
const image = [
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_1',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_2',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_3',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_4',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_5',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_6',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_7',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_8',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_9',
'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/272727/ff9900?text=F_10',
];

const layerShadowSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.layer-shadow-slider');
const ticker = document.querySelectorAll('.ticker');

for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
  ticker[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image[i] + ')';
  ticker[i].style.transform = 'rotateY(' + (i + 1) * 36 + 'deg) translateZ(430px)';
}

const wrapTicker = document.querySelector('#wrap-ticker')

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {

})
/* изменения в коде */


function MyMatrix() {

}


MyMatrix.prototype.matrix3d = function() {
  layerShadowSlider[1].innerHTML = arguments[14];
  //console.log('matrix3d', arguments[14]); // Предпоследний аргумент - положение по Z. 
}

var MM = new MyMatrix();

function getPoisition() {
  for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
    var method = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(ticker[0])["transform"];
    // Чуть чуть извращений
    eval('MM.' + method);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(getPoisition);
}
requestAnimationFrame(getPoisition);

/* изменения в коде */
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.layer-shadow-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: inset 50px 0px 100px 50px rgba(39, 39, 39, 1);
}

.layer-shadow-slider:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: inset -50px 0px 100px 50px rgba(39, 39, 39, 1);
}

#main-wrap-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

#wrap-ticker {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: rotate 60s linear infinite;
}

.ticker {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main-wrap-slider">
    <div id="wrap-ticker">
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer-shadow-slider"></div>
  <div class="layer-shadow-slider" style="font-size: 50px; color:white; line-height: 5; text-align: center;"></div>
</div>
```

Вопрос: Как можно определить положение элемента `<span class="ticker"></span>` по оси `Z`?

После коммента  `Other`  попытался так. Смотрите `изменения в коде`. (устарел)

После ответа `Stepan Kasyanenko` в третий раз редактирую вопрос. Но или я что-то не делаю или ответ не тот который мне нужен...

Смотрите изменения в коде

Comment: а ещё фоточки есть?

Comment: `console.info(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(ticker[i], null).getPropertyValue('zIndex'));`?

Comment: @Other, не получилось... До твоего коммента пробовал, но увы...  Глянь я изменил пример...

Comment: @norbornen, `yandex` - тебе в помощь...))) Найдешь, что душе угодно

Comment: Что вы понимаете под положением по оси `Z`? Наверное не значение `zIndex`, а скорее всего `translateZ`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, там `translateZ` уже выставлен и имеет значение `translateZ(430px)`, мне надо получить положение каждого элемента каждый раз при трансформации.  `.getComputedStyle()` - берет значение из стилей

Comment: Вот это я и пытаюсь узнать - что за положение вы хотите получить? У вас они крутятся вокруг оси `Y`. что вы хотите узнать?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Объясню по простому...  Хочу присвоить тому или иному элементу `<span class="ticker"></span>` какой-нибудь `class`, если он спереди и удалить `class`, если он ушел с переднего плана

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения по простому! Теперь мне стало понятно, что вы хотие получить значение угла `rotateY`. Посмотрите мой ответ - может быть поможет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить через `getComputedStyle` значение `transform`, которое будет являться, в вашем случае, `matrix3d`, которая в свою очередь описывает трансформацию нашего элемента, включая `rotate`, `scale`, `translate`.

Есть статья на [хабре](https://habr.com/post/166751/) (или в [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#mathematical-description), я не осилил), описывающая значения этой матрицы.

Пример, как получить значение `traslateZ` из элемента.

```js
const image = [
  'https://www.prodaman.ru/users/5824/photos/users/91721_big.jpg',
  'https://cdn1.kolektado.com/media/cache/profile_photo_thumb/0a/c1/30a031c98ab4ac27fce46377bb70.jpeg',
  'http://dlm6.meta.ua/pic/0/33/31/2se9MTgTyR.jpg',
  'http://ladyjob.com.ua/application/content/news/5483.jpg',
]

const ticker = document.querySelectorAll('.ticker');

for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
  ticker[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image[i] + ')';
  ticker[i].style.transform = 'translateZ(' + (i + 1) * 10 + 'px) translateX(' + (i + 1) * 10 + 'px)';
}



function MyMatrix() {

}

MyMatrix.prototype.matrix3d = function() {
  console.log('traslateZ', arguments[14]); // Предпоследний аргумент - положение по Z. 
}

var MM = new MyMatrix();


function getPoisition() {
  for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
    var method = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(ticker[i])["transform"];
    // Чуть чуть извращений
    eval('MM.' + method);
  }
}
getPoisition();

shuffle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
    var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    ticker[i].style.transform = 'translateZ(' + random + 'px) translateX(' + (i + 1) * 10 + 'px)';
  }
  getPoisition();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ticker {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="ticker"></span>
<span class="ticker"></span>
<span class="ticker"></span>
<span class="ticker"></span>

<button id="shuffle">shuffle</button>
```

Пример вычислений угла поворота по оси `Y`, а именно значения `rotateY`.

```js
const image = [
  'https://www.prodaman.ru/users/5824/photos/users/91721_big.jpg',
  'https://cdn1.kolektado.com/media/cache/profile_photo_thumb/0a/c1/30a031c98ab4ac27fce46377bb70.jpeg',
  'http://dlm6.meta.ua/pic/0/33/31/2se9MTgTyR.jpg',
  'http://ladyjob.com.ua/application/content/news/5483.jpg',
]

const ticker = document.querySelectorAll('.ticker');

for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
  ticker[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image[i] + ')';
  ticker[i].style.transform = 'rotateY(' + (i + 1) * 10 + 'deg) translateX(' + (i + 1) * 100 + 'px)';
}



function MyMatrix() {

}

MyMatrix.prototype.matrix3d = function() {
  console.log('rotateY', this.toDegree(Math.acos(arguments[0]))) // Первый аргумент - косинус угла в радианах. Переводим его в градусы
}
MyMatrix.prototype.toDegree = function(rad) {
  return Math.round(rad * 180 / Math.PI);
}

var MM = new MyMatrix();


function getPoisition() {
  for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
    var method = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(ticker[i])["transform"];
    // Чуть чуть извращений
    eval('MM.' + method);
  }
}
getPoisition();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ticker {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="ticker"></span>
<span class="ticker"></span>
<span class="ticker"></span>
<span class="ticker"></span>
```

Финальный вариант - высчитывание текущего элемента, который показывается на первом плане.

```js
const image = [
  'https://www.prodaman.ru/users/5824/photos/users/91721_big.jpg',
  'https://cdn1.kolektado.com/media/cache/profile_photo_thumb/0a/c1/30a031c98ab4ac27fce46377bb70.jpeg',
  'http://dlm6.meta.ua/pic/0/33/31/2se9MTgTyR.jpg',
  'http://ladyjob.com.ua/application/content/news/5483.jpg',
  'https://articles.abilogic.com/data/uploads/0000098000/600/abi_0000098616.thumb.100.jpg',
  'https://freelance.boutique/img/avatars/302073.png',
  'http://by.badgood.info/photos/avatars/16463/29215eefb9.jpg',
  'http://pda.svidanok.net/files/imagecache/thumb/images/users/irishka89_uid36441_00000.jpg',
  'http://vseotzyvy.ru/media/cache/a1/ee/a1ee8d99a67b9a355c44b2e9557141b2.jpg',
  'https://ц.укр/uploads/users/484396/100_791b00bc996a467.jpg'
];

const layerShadowSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.layer-shadow-slider');
const ticker = document.querySelectorAll('.ticker');

for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
  ticker[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image[i] + ')';
  ticker[i].style.transform = 'rotateY(' + (i + 1) * 36 + 'deg) translateZ(430px)';
  ticker[i].textContent = i;
}

const wrapTicker = document.querySelector('#wrap-ticker')

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {

})
/* изменения в коде */


function MyMatrix() {

}


MyMatrix.prototype.matrix3d = function() {
  return [].slice.call(arguments);
}

MyMatrix.prototype.toDegree = function(rad) {
  return Math.round(rad * 180 / Math.PI);
}

var MM = new MyMatrix();

function getPoisition() {
  var method = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('wrap-ticker'))["transform"];
  // Чуть чуть извращений
  try {
    var matrix3d = eval('MM.' + method);
    var rotateY = MM.toDegree(Math.acos(matrix3d[0]));
    var currentI = Math.round(rotateY / 36);
    layerShadowSlider[1].textContent = Math.abs(currentI - 9);
  } catch (e) {}
  requestAnimationFrame(getPoisition);

}
requestAnimationFrame(getPoisition);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.layer-shadow-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: inset 50px 0px 100px 50px rgba(39, 39, 39, 1);
}

.layer-shadow-slider:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: inset -50px 0px 100px 50px rgba(39, 39, 39, 1);
}

#main-wrap-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

#wrap-ticker {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: rotate 60s linear infinite;
}

.ticker {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main-wrap-slider">
    <div id="wrap-ticker">
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
      <span class="ticker"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer-shadow-slider"></div>
  <div class="layer-shadow-slider" style="font-size: 50px; color:white; line-height: 5; text-align: center;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, перечитай вопрос я там изменил кое что, вроде не то, что не нужно или я что-то не то делаю...

Comment: @Air вы не тот пример взяли. В вашем случае вам нужен второй пример из моего ответа, который высчитывает угод поворота `rotateY`. Да и логика странная немного... Вы записываете в элемент, в цикле, значение `rotateY` всех `.ticker`. Наверное, вам надо найти такой `.ticker`, у которого значение 'rotateY' будт близко к `0` или `360`, с некоторой погрешностью.

Comment: Пока твой коммент увидел, уже подумал, и сделал так как у тя в втором примере...

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, будь другом, подскажи на наглядном примере, как связать это все вместе, не соображу голова не работает...

Comment: @Air у меня что-то тоже замкнуло, не смог по человечески угол поворота посчитать, поэтому лови немного ужасного кода. Вариант третий - то, что ты хочешь.

Comment: Не то... Но я приму твой ответ, так как с твоей помощью я понял куда двигаться...  Я нашел данные,  но пока думаю как их найти...  Если пример запустишь отдельным файлом на компе в браузере с полноценной консолью, выдели любой  из элементов, увидишь при прокрутке выдает координаты положения, только пока не знаю, что за данные это... Я еще не волшебник, все только учусь...  В отличии от тебя я никогда прототипы не использовал... Щас будет впервые... Надо бы этот мой пробел заполнить...

Comment: @Air как это не то? Ваш комментарий *Хочу присвоить тому или иному элементу <span class="ticker"></span> какой-нибудь class, если он спереди и удалить class, если он ушел с переднего плана*. Мой третий пример определяет какой элемент сейчас на переднем плане, добавляй, убирай класс, как тебе понравится. И кстати, что за координаты - покажи в вопросе.

Comment: Дело в том, что ответ решает задачу в целом.  Но на мой взгляд это костыль.

Comment: @Air а почему костыль?

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, глянь, я кое что снял... Может понятнее будет, что именно я хочу найти...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsfuokkNrmk

Comment: @Air При данной разметке положение `.ticker` узнать не получится, т.к. вы меняете `transform` не им, а родительскому элементу `#wrap-ticker`. Вот если переделаете разметку и стили, что бы анимировать\менять значение `transform` именно `.ticker`, тогда сможете воспользоваться моим вторым примером.

Comment: Согласен, была такая мысль.... Но я знаю точно одно, если эти данные есть у браузера и он их показывает, значит их можно получить...

Comment: @Air интересно, откуда у вас такая уверенность в этом?) Не все, что показывает браузер, можно получить)

Comment: Логика... А на кой тогда это браузеру?