# Как вытащить угол поворота из matrix3d?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, матрицы

У блока задается поворот через matrix3d. Как вытащить угол поворота по каждой оси?

Comment: Можете использовать getComputedStyle. Посмотрите мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832431/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8-z/832669#832669

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko можете, пожалуйста, пояснить, почему вы получаете угол только через один арккосинус? Ведь поворот в matrix3d задается четырьмя значениями

Comment: Потому что мне в той задачи нужно было получить угол для определенной оси, а именно `Y`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko тогда у меня другой вопрос. Насколько я знаю, так задается поворот по Y:
[Поворот по Y](https://i.imgur.com/FZF5XL8.jpg).
А так для Z:
[Поворот по Z](https://i.imgur.com/b9eiPht.jpg).

Из чего следует, что если будет задан поворот по Z и Y одновременно, вычисление только через один арккосинус (элемент 11) даст неверный результат?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если да, то как это можно обойти? Использовать другой элемент?

Comment: Почему это даст не верный результат? У вас будет два значения: 1) поворот по Y, 2) поворот по Z. Вы хотите одним значением описать поворот сразу по двум осям? У вас вопрос **Как вытащить угол поворота по каждой оси?**. Вы вычисляете два значения. Не обязательно брать элемент 11.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko все, понял, спасибо большое. Имел ввиду, что при одновременном повороте по Y и Z матрицы перемножаются и в 11 будет уже не Y, а из произведение.